# How to implement CLU (conversational language understanding) in Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am new to Bot Framework Composer and have a requirement to integrate CLU (Conversational Language Understanding) within the Bot Framework Composer. Could anyone please provide guidance with this integration?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation, to enable CLU in Bot Framework Composer you must first install the [CLU recognizer package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CLURecognizer) from NuGet in your Composer project.

[image]

Once the package is installed you can configure the Conversation Language Understanding recognizer.
[image]
And add your CLU model and deployment details in `json` format:

```json
{
  "$kind": "Microsoft.CluRecognizer",
  "projectName": "<your project name>",
  "endpoint": "<your endpoint, including https://>",
  "endpointKey": "<your endpoint key>",
  "deploymentName": "<your deployment name>"
}
```

For more details you can refer to this [documentation.](https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/ConversationLanguageUnderstanding/dotnet)

You can also check this CoreBotCLU Sample [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/conversational-language-understanding/tutorials/bot-framework) for reference.

**Note:** As of now Composer does not integrate natively with Conversation Language Understanding, so managing intents and entities **must** be done in the Language Studio portal instead of Composer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks RishabhM!